# What is the history behind "Blonde moment"?

Tags: expressions, politeness, history

Why when someone does something stupid they use "blonde moment"? 
Isn't it racist or sexist?

I am not blond, but to me it is not polite to say such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

> **having a blonde moment**

can and is used by both blondes and brunettes, usually women, with the meaning of forgetfulness, silliness, being distracted, or slow.  It can be used jokingly in a self-deprecating way

> Sorry, I just had a **blonde moment**.

A funny **blonde moment** for Reese Witherspoon can bee seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ztVNwO0CyE&t=0m30s)

The expression is not necessarily offensive and should not be confused with

> **dumb blonde**

which is considered derogatory.

The origin of **blonde moment** is cited as late 20th century [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=blonde+moment+meaning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and may possibly have been used to counter the long held belief that blondes are more desirable as evidenced by more brunettes colouring their hair blonde than vice versa.

There was a famous campaign for Clairol hair colouring which asked:

> **Do blondes have more fun**?

The origin of **dumb blonde** goes back further

> The roots of this notion may be traced to Europe, with the "dumb blonde" in question being a French courtesan named Rosalie Duthé, satirised in a 1775 play Les curiosites de la Foire for her habit of pausing a long time before speaking, appearing not only stupid but literally dumb (in the sense of mute). [Blonde Stereotype Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blonde_stereotype)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you get when you Google "[what are blonde jokes](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20are%20blonde%20jokes)" is:

> Blonde jokes are a class of jokes based on a stereotype of dumb blonde women. These jokes about people, generally women, who have blonde hair serve as a form of blonde versus brunette rivalry.

This is more of an offensive stereotype than a sexist or racism statement. There is no law that is violated when you use "blonde jokes". However, they are considered to be very rude and blondes actually get very offended by this.

> I guess I've been a dumb blond about it.

These were used extensively until people started realizing that not all blondes are dumb. A few very dumb people happened to be blondes and that must be the start of that stereotype.

But since *"Dumb Blonde"* refers to a woman, and not a blonde man, it can be considered as a sexist statement too, which is a punishable offense.

Comment: The 'dumb blonde' thing was popularised by Goldie Hawn in a late 60's television show called "Rowan and Martin's laugh-in".  Political correctness had not been invented at the time.

Comment: @JavaLatte, Oh, all right. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks. But try using it now and see how many people give you "the look".

Comment: The first time I heard that being used was on [The Pink Panther](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=the%20pink%20panther), when Steve Martin underwent a session to correct his racist and sexist phrases.

Comment: @JavaLatte I would say Goldie Hawn was more a **ditzy**, loveable blonde, than just a dumb blonde. "Veeery interesting... but blonde...."

Comment: Also note that there are blondes who use these jokes as a form of self-deprecating humor. Minor spelling note: *blond* for men, *blonde* for women.

Comment: @Peter: it was that Goldie Hawn's ditzy loveableness that made it acceptable at that time to stereotype dumb blondes...  many women wanted to be that dumb blonde. And as Era says, they still do...

Comment: What's not to love? [**Here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HqXXAxLd0k&t=0m23s) with Mr Dean Martin. Women wanted to be her, men wanted to be with her. Those eyes and that laugh helped a lot also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is sexist.

It refers to the cliché of the "Dumb Blonde" (examples all over the Internet).

It is not political correct and can be quite offensive - and false, obviously.

As I fall roughly into the optical category, I have received my fair share of  these "jokes" and typically answer by pointing out that *"I'm proud to be a member of a small exclusive genetic minority which is luckily entirely unrelated to my intellectual capabilities or academic success"*.

Comment: Stephie, I am so glad to see a woman answering my question. As you mentioned, that is clearly false! There is no reason to judge people based on any factor regarding their appearance or gender. And if someone does, I believe they are the dumb one! But I was just wondering why they use this expression and where it originally came from. Surprisingly enough, I heard it from a colleague who is generally a nice guy and that is when I started wondering about this expression!